# Matching characters in first column

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a custom syntax highlighting file (*.vim) and comments for the language are either a '.', '*', or '+' starting in the first column of the line.

```
.comment
*comment
+comment
  not a comment
```

Is there a way to match these types of comments?  I've tried

```
syn match myComment '(\s)@![.|*|+]*.*'
```

Basically, I tried testing for no whitespace, because I wanted to start in the first column, but it does not work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` atom matches in the first column:

```
syn match myComment '^[.*+].*'
```

#### Additional critique

Also, your regular expression syntax is off:

- Unless you switch to *very magic* mode by prepending `\v`, you have to escape the `\(...\)` capture group and the `\@!` multi.
- Inside the collection `[...]`, you don't separate via `\|`.

Comment: awesome thank you!  yes I need a little more practice with my regex, thanks for the tips